# Cannot put MacBook Air to sleep

Tags: sleep-wake

#### Problem

I have a MacBook Air (2020) running MacOS Monterey (12.2.1) which will not go to sleep. I also cannot put it to sleep manually (the option is greyed out from the Apple menu and the keyboard shortcut does not work). Closing the display does not put the laptop to sleep either. For example, if I'm playing music, it will continue to play even after closing the display.

#### Attempted solutions

- Restarting computer
- Shutting down computer
- Restarting in Safe mode
- Resetting NVRAM
- Running `sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.PowerManagement SystemPowerSettings -dict SleepDisabled -bool NO` from the command line and then restarting again

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try entering `sudo pmset -a disablesleep 0` into your Terminal App.

Basically I had this need of [stopping my MacBook from sleeping](https://windowsreport.com/mac/play-music-lid-closed-mac/) so I can have music playing with lid closed.  Before using an app called "Amphetamine", my way of approach is to use commands in Terminal to modify some system's internal things. When sleep is disabled this way, all the above things you mentioned above happens.

Therefore the command I suggested should, theoretically (re)enable sleep.

Comment: Wow, that did it. Thank you! Now I'll forever wonder how that got switched in the first place.